# Баг при бинарной записи в файл. Запись в бинарный файл Объектов C++. cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, структуры, ввод, fstream, binary-file

1)У меня есть класс, который мне нужно либо записать в файл, либо вывести все записи одной структуры из файла в консоль. Возможно ли записать/считать объект, в котором поля - другие объекты, но все поля в тех объектах тоже определённой длины(т.е. я не использую динамические массивы, вектора и string), в файл так :  `fs.write/read((char*)&object,sizeof(Class));`

2)При попытке записать самое первое поле

```
char name[128];
    void set_name() {
            cout << "Enter name of player: ";
            cin.getline(name,128);
        }
```

Это поле игнорируется, но точно такое же поле `club`, с аналогичным методом программа просит заполнить.[image: Without cin.ignor()] Если вставляю `cin.ignore()` перед `cin.getline()`, то вначале всё работает как надо, но после нескольких полей перестаёт запрашивать ввод и заполняет всё пропусками, при этом никакой ошибки не выдаёт.
Если добавлять `cin.ignore()` , причём не важно куда, хоть в одно место(перед name) хоть во все остальные, то происходит это [image: With cin.ignore()]

Comment: Давайте конкретнее - покажите код. Первый способ работает для POD, но вы точно гарантируете, что у вас именно POD?... По второму вопросу - смешиваете getline и >>...

Comment: @Harry И насчёт второго вопроса, не понял как смешать getline и >>

Comment: @Harry Насчёт POD , у меня только char и int , но что-то вроде такого 
Class object{
class2 object2;} А вот там char и int

Comment: Вот пример https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-class-objects-fromto-file-c/amp/

Comment: @Harry Вот код https://github.com/Jettio/C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По 1 пункту - да, ваши классы отвечают требованиям POD, так что вы можете их записывать/читать в бинарные файлы таким образом - через read/write, только не забудьте открывать файл как бинарный. И, естественно, при изменении описания класса или там опций компилятора (скажем, с другим выравниванием) совместимость может нарушиться - т.е. если записать одной программой, а считать потом другой, скомпилированной иначе или с измененными классами (скажем, порядком полей) - то прочтется совсем не то, что запишется...

По второму - просто `ignore()` игнорирует единственный символ. Чтобы пропустить все до конца строки, используется вызов наподобие

```
input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Т.е. игнорировать все ("ну очень много" :)) до конца строки. При этом это лучше делать *после* чтения типа

```
cin >> threshold[i];
```

а не до. Более подробно разбирать ваш код не очень тянет... Если не справитесь с "игнорами" - наберите в текстовый файл ваш ввод, который приводит к сбоям - ну, чтоб его можно было перенаправить типа

```
main.exe < input.txt
```

Тогда можно будет посмотреть, на чем именно слет получается.

Comment: Код на самом деле не такой ёмкий, всё сделано по единому шаблону (т.е. достаточно посмотреть один метод, все остальные работают по такому же принципу) , а в программе я просто вызываю данные методы в потоке ввода/вывода (т.е. одна программа и читает и записывает). Часть после "что если я не справлюсь с игнорами" - я не понял.